# Can I use Google Analytics 4 custom dimensions in the Analysis Hub?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, analytics-events, google-analytics-4

In the Analysis Hub:

[image]

Can I use a custom dimension I've previously added?

[image]

For example:

I'll send the following events and I would like to do analysis based on one of its parameters:

```
gtag("event", "my_custom_event", {
  my_custom_dimension: "SOME_VALUE"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Click the + next to the Dimensions heading and you can add more dimensions to use in the report, including the custom ones.